# Order confirmation email not going for Authorize.net payment method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, authorize.net

I am using magento2.2. In my site order, confirmations emails are going for Cash on delivery payment but order confirmation emails are not going for Authorize.net  payment method.

Any idea why order confirmation emails are not going for Authorize.net  payment method? How can I debug?